# clang-tidy -fix does not apply any changes

Tags: clang-tidy

I'm running `clang-tidy` with the following command:

```
run-clang-tidy.py -checks="-*,cppcoreguidelines-*,hicpps-*" -header-filter=".*" -fix"
```

(or `clang-tidy -checks="-*,cppcoreguidelines-*,hicpps-*" -header-filter=".*" -fix"` also works)

This returns a lot of errors. It also says `applying fixes...` in the terminal since I added the `-fix` option.

My problem is that for the `cppcoreguidelines-*` and `hicpps-*` fixes are not applied, only shown. Does the checks that I have choose not to support fixing my 1000 problems?

Comment: Have you tried it on a smaller number of files/checks or a single file and check? What are the errors it returns?

Comment: Sorry for my language, but when I wrote that the command returned a lot of errors I meant a list of rules that I'm breaking in my code (clang errors). The command behaves as it should returning this errors list but does not apply the fixes for the errors with the - fix option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `-fix-errors` option instead of just `-fix`. The latter will not apply any fixes if compiler errors are present.
See the [clang-tidy documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/#id2):

```
  -fix                          -
                                  Apply suggested fixes. Without -fix-errors
                                  clang-tidy will bail out if any compilation
                                  errors were found.
  -fix-errors                   -
                                  Apply suggested fixes even if compilation
                                  errors were found. If compiler errors have
                                  attached fix-its, clang-tidy will apply them as
                                  well.
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same issue while I was trying to automatically apply clang-tidy fixes via LLVM's `run-clang-tidy` python script:

The **Root of the problem**
for me was a mismatch of the `run-clang-tidy.py script`, `clang-tidy` and  the version of `clang-apply-replacements`.
The latter was version 10 instead of 11, so installing `clang-tidy-11` and linking `clang-apply-replacements` to the `clang-apply-replacements-11`  fixed the issue for me. I also downloaded the `run-clang-tidy` script from LLVM's repository with the matching tag.

**Is this also the cause of your problem**?
If the reported versions don't match, similar steps might also solve your problem.

```sh
clang++ --version
clang-tidy --version
clang-apply-replacements --version
```